# Unknown lifecycle phase during mvn versions:set

Tags: maven

I'm trying to release a multi-module maven project. Currently at 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT and am trying to bump the project version to 1.0.0-b1 for all modules in the tree.

Maven fails with an "Unknown lifecycle phase ".0.0-b1" error", suggesting I don't quite know what. Looks like the version number isn't being parsed correctly and bleeding over into some phase setting. The build seems to fail on the root module but the error message is totally inscrutable

```
>  mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=1.0.0-b1 -X 
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------  Building GOSAC-N Services Open Source Distribution 1 
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ ] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources,
> process-sources, generate-resources, process-resou compile,
> process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources,
> generate-test-resources, process-test-resou test-compile,
> process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package,
> pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-i tion-test, verify,
> install, deploy] ] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean] ]
> Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy] 
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------  Reactor Summary:
> 
>  GOSAC-N Services Open Source Distribution ......... FAILURE [0.016s] 
> Commons ........................................... SKIPPED
```

I'm doing this from the command line (Powershell) under Windoze 7 if that matters. Project builds fine with mvn install BTW.

Comment: This seems to be a PowerShell problem. Running the same command in a plain cmd window works correctly.

Strangely, doublequoting the version string gives this...

mvn versions:set -DnewVersion="1.0.0-b1"
>>
like its missing a quote or something.

Comment: Maybe it is plugin problem. For example, [`maven-release-plugin`](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRELEASE-511) also does not like "strange" versions.

Answer (score 0):

For me, maven had a problem with the project setup.

It was just that one of my component modules had the parent module as its parent in its POM, but the parent module didn't have it as a child module:

`MyParent pom.xml:`

```xml
<modules><!--nothing here--></modules>
```

`MyChild pom.xml:`

```xml
<parent>
    <artifactId>MyParent</artifactId>
</parent>
```

And that's why the `mvn versions:set` has not worked properly. So maybe if someone in the future finds this problem try to check if all modules' parents and children are correctly set.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue when using the terminal inside IntelliJ. As @Bradjcox said, I think this is a terminal issue. I managed to make it work on IntelliJ using simple quote or double quote, like this:

`mvn versions:set -DnewVersion="1.0.2"`

`mvn versions:set -DnewVersion='1.0.2'`

When I tried on Windows, using quotes caused them to be placed in the pom file.